# java use regex，how to change sentence "This is an #apple#." to "This is an ____."?

Tags: java, regexp-replace

I want to find inside my string a sequence of characters starting and ending with `#`, and replace it with four underscores: `____`. And the position of "#" in sentence is not sure.

For example, changing

```
"This is an #apple#. But I like #pears#. #Can# I have some pears?"
```

to

```
"This is an ____.But I like ____ . ____ I have some pears?"
```

Comment: So what regex did you try to come up with and where did you fail?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? if the string both startsWith and endsWith a`#`, replace it with `____`.

Comment: The word length of apple isn't 3 or 10. What is the actual requirement?

Comment: I'd interpret the question as follows: in a string there might be a sequence of an unknown number of characters starting and ending with `#` which needs to be replaced by 4 underscores. This should be fairly easy to do with `String.replace(regex, "____")` - so the question seems to be what that regex should be. @zhangjin am I correct?

Comment: @Thomas yes ,you are right!

Comment: @Thomas can you tell me detail regex?

Comment: What did you try so far? Try to translate "starts with #, followed by andything not #, ends with #" to a regex.

Comment: @khelwood any word between two #,like `#pears#`,`#banana#`。

Comment: I see absolutely no attempt at writing the regex yourself, which indicates that you don't know regex at all, so how about you go online and **start learning regex**, instead of asking us to write your code for you?

Comment: I've edited your question. Please check that it describes what you actually want.

Comment: @Andreas Regex is difficult for me !

Answer (score 2):

```
        String str = "This is an #apple#. But I like #pears#.";
        String reg = "#.*?#";
        str = str.replaceAll(reg, "____");
        System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: so you have answered your own question?  Or this should be an edit to your question?

Comment: @AlexRudenko I find right regex! and answered 。

Comment: @AlexRudenko Since it seems to be a good solution, I'd say that OP just needed a push to try themselves.